# Keep X-sessions active when I switch to another TTY

Tags: xorg, tty, streaming, music-player, text-mode

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 server and I use startx [application] to run any graphical applications.  When I use Opera browser or any other browser and play music, when I switch to another tty, the music will stop.
Is there something I can do to keep the music playing when I switch to another tty?  Eventually I want to use Nuvola player to stream music from Amazon while I'm working on other things in other tty consoles. What might be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Access to devices is based on your user.

Once you login with your user on e.g. TTY1, you should still/again hear the sound (maybe switch back and forth once) but you can never have the sound when going to TTY1 in the first place as there is no user logged in to actually have control over the outputs.